# Installing Windows 7 over Ubuntu, partition problem

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu about 2 months ago, and now with so many problems i've decides to go back to the old Windows 7.

My problem is, that when i installed Ubuntu on my new HDD, i made the whole partition as ext4 so i can't install Windows. So how i can now partition that thing in to NTFS?

I'm doing it via USB. Here's the picture from GParted. (http://postimg.org/image/e70h9lzad/)

Comment: you have to unmount the partition first before you can manipulate it!

Comment: Problem is that i can't do the unmount process via GParted.

Comment: it looks like you are not running a live-system! - it should be clear that you can't unmount a used root-/home-partition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to boot from your live Ubuntu, you cannot change the root partition otherwise! Then start Gparted and shrink your ubuntu root partition. try to shrink it from the start, to get the free space at the front - windows do not like starting from way inside a partition.
Leave the free space unformated for windows.
Reboot using your windows usb installer, and install in free space!
After windows have installed you will need to boot your pc with your ubuntu live usb and reinstall or repair the Grub boot loader, else you will not be able to run Ubuntu.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting is similar to trying to pick out the engine of a car while it is running.

To install another operating system: Make sure to boot the new (other OS) installation media and handle the re-partitioning from there.